# Restrict tomcat in spring boot to certain ip addresses

Tags: java, spring, security, tomcat, spring-boot

I need to restrict the embedded tomcat of a spring boot based application to certain ip addresses. I want to allow only incoming connections from two ip addresses and not all.
I know how to do this in a tomcat that is not running embedded but don't know a way to configure this in spring boot. The various `server.tomcat.*` properties don't seem to offer support for this. There is the property `server.address` that enables me to bind to a local ip address, but that is not what I need.

Comment: If you know how to do it in a standalone container it shouldn't be hard to find the API in Tomcat (probably a `Valve` or a `Connector` property - it will be obvious from your server.xml). It's easy for clients to spoof their IP address though, so it might be better to stick to something else if security is your goal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found this answer searching for the same solution.  This is a more accurate way of doing it within Spring Boot.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean remoteAddressFilter() {

    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    RemoteAddrFilter filter = new RemoteAddrFilter();

    filter.setAllow("192.168.0.2");
    filter.setDenyStatus(404);

    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

    return filterRegistrationBean;

}
```

The default response is a 403.  To change that to a 404 this is added `filter.setDenyStatus(404);`

You can also set Deny addresses instead with `filter.setDeny("192\\.168\\.0\\.2");`

[RemoteAddressFilter Docs for Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add multiple IP addresses then you can do that by using Spring Security with a custom Authentication Provider. The custom Authentication Provider configuration is as follows:

```java
@Component
public class CustomIpAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

   Set<String> whitelist = new HashSet<String>();

    public CustomIpAuthenticationProvider() {
        whitelist.add("103.219.56.22");
        whitelist.add("192.168.2.33");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {

        WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
        String userIp = details.getRemoteAddress();

        if(! whitelist.contains(userIp)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid IP Address");
        }
    }
}
```

And the Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomIpAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and().formLogin().permitAll()
          .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Or if you want only some particular mappings to be accessed from some specific IP addresses then the Spring Security configuration is as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/rockstar/**").hasIpAddress("103.219.55.22")
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin().permitAll()
          .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good answer but it is an application IP filtrer, the answer above is a container IP filter, which is a much a far better solution